# Regex Incorrectly Satisfies Two Funnel Conversion Goals in Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics

I am trying to build some Conversion Funnel Goals for our website, except that successful Conversion of Funnel 2) also counts as a Conversion for Funnel 1).

I have set the Conversion Goals as URL destinations. I tested the REGEXP in Rubular (https://snag.gy/ZFt6l5.jpg) to differentiate between the lead form on the home page vs the lead form on /landing-pages/.

1) Home --> Lead Form --> Lead Form Completion (destination URL)

Actual URLs are:

https://example.com/ -->

https://example.com/a-3-lightbox.html -->

https://example.com/a-form_confirmation.html?name=example&email=example@gmail.com

The REGEXP I have used is:

```
\/ -> /[a-z]-\d-lightbox\.html -> \/[a-z]-form_confirmation\.html?.*
```

~~~~~~

2) Home --> Landing Pages --> Landing Page Lead Form --> Landing Page Lead Form Completion

Actual URLS are:

https://example.com/ -->

https://example.com/landing-pages/a-3-lightbox.html -->

https://example.com/landing-pages/a-form_confirmation.html?name=example&email=example@gmail.com

The REGEXP is:

```
\/ -> \/landing-pages\/ -> \/landing-pages\/[a-z]-\d-lightbox\.html -> \/landing-pages\/[a-z]-form_confirmation\.html?.*
```

Now I'm guessing this occurs because `[a-z]-form_confirmation\.html?.*`
satisfies the last portion of the URL in both.

Now I don't think I can use `equals to` when setting the destination URL as we are using Unbounce landing pages to split test, which will cause the last portion of the URL to change depending on the variant (e.g. a, b, c, d).

Would anyone be able to suggest something?

Thanks!

Comment: I hope you are not seriously collecting email and names into GA in the URLs. That is considered a violation of terms of use.

Comment: No we're not. We're using Unbounce and I wanted to determine what the Confirmation Url was :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume your arrows mean that you are using a funnel. The tricky bit here is that the funnel does not affect goal conversions. Funnels are merely a visualization thing.

That means the Urls preceding the goal url are not taken into account when the goal is evaluated. The only thing GA cares about is the destination Url.

Your first regular expression matches both `/a-form-confirmation` and `/landingpage/a-form-confirmation`. Since GA does not look at the preceding funnel steps this Goal will be triggered both for your first and second set of example Urls.

The remedy, as sdhaus has already pointed out, is to make your first regular expression more specific by specifying that it must not start with a path, but must start with the actual phrase you want to match.

The way to do this is to add a caret character "^" at the start of the regular expression, meaning "has to start with the following character(s)".

Comment: Thanks!

Upvoted as the solution as it has the most comprehensive explanation :) 

I actually just got it explained here too: https://www.en.advertisercommunity.com/t5/Google-Analytics-Tracking-Goals/Regex-Incorrectly-Satisfies-Two-Funnel-Conversion-Goals-in/m-p/874373#M6995

Comment: In my Goal Conversions, I have the first step set to 'Required', so the Goals will ONLY be triggered if they travel through the funnel flow that I have depicted - please correct me if I'm wrong :)

Comment: No. They will only show up in the funnel if they have  the first step (without the setting it would be possible to enter the funnel at a later step), but unless something has changed recently the "required step" does not affect conversion.

Answer (score 1):

You can expand your regex to include a 'Starts with' '^' at the beginning of your confirmation URL.

Comment: Thanks :) I just got it explained here too: https://www.en.advertisercommunity.com/t5/Google-Analytics-Tracking-Goals/Regex-Incorrectly-Satisfies-Two-Funnel-Conversion-Goals-in/m-p/874373#M6995